# read/download all documents within corporate

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any account or method could read/download all documents within our corporate, not just those sent through API account?
or we have to add this API account as a copy recipient for all signing documents?

Answer (score 0):

Your API user would have to have 'Account-Wide Rights' (the Administrator profile has this by default).

This setting would be under **Users > 'API User' > Permissions**

This will open up the access for that user to the entire accounts documents, not just the documents for that user.

Comment: hi,thanks for reply.

We are using admin as the API user. I checked the permission of the admin account, the Account-wide rights is checked.
But when I login in with the account, I couldn't see the docusign sent by other users. Is that right?

Comment: In the member console? You do not automatically see all of the other's sent documents in Manage. You could see the status of them in Envelope Publish or share out that user's folder to you, to see the envelope data in the member console.

Comment: Thanks. From the console, I could see that envelop that other users shared to admin, but could we get the envelop status or download them with the API?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed response. Yes you can get that information through the API if you have `Account-Wide Rights` turned on for the user making the call.